# Xcode 6 Beta 5 error - use of unresolved identifier '..'

Tags: xcode, xcode6

I dont know why I'm getting this error? I am using Xcode 6 beta 5

```
func random() ->UInt32 {
    var range = UInt32(50)..UInt32(200)
    return range.startIndex + arc4random_uniform(range.endIndex - range.startIndex + 1)
```

I get the error - use of unresolved identifier '..'

Please help, thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In beta 3, the half-closed range operator was changed from `..` to `..<`. So your second line should be this instead:

`var range = UInt32(50)..<UInt32(200)`